# WxPython exit button doesn´t always works

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using a code designed by another person in MAC OS. I am using Windows instead and have slightly modified it, but the problem comes when using the GUI that is created.

I have already dealt with a similar issue with a slider. Once I pressed the slider, I couldn´t release it or press another button. I was forced to quit the GUI and start again. I solved it by changing the event command from EVT_COMMAND_SCROLL to EVT_COMMAND_SCROLL_THUMBTRACK. However I did not understand why it worked in MAC OS and does not work in Windows.

Now, I want to close the GUI with the typical cross inside the red button in the right corner of the window. I can do it if it is the first order I do in the GUI. If I first press any button or slider, the exit button does not work.

It made me consider if a major problem is hidden in the code which I am not seeing. I am new at wxPython, which is the module used in the code.

I just ask for your opinion and hope it is a basic error.

Thanks very much

Comment: It seems you have a problem with code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: One possibility that would fit the description is that there is a `CaptureMouse()` without a corresponding `ReleaseMouse()`.

Comment: We need code to help. Either edit with a minimal example or link to something like Pastebin with a larger one